# Asymptotic Solver for Nonlinear Singular Perturbations

Tags: nonlinear, asymptotics

I would like to ask if there are any built-in functions / packages that allow one to obtain asymptotic expansions for nonlinear singular perturbations.
More specifically, I am dealing with perturbations that look like this:

eqn = {by''[x] + (y'[x])^(2)(y[x] + y'[x]) == 0,y[0] == 0, y[1] == 3}, where the perturbation parameter b approaches zero.

I tried using AsymptoticDSolveValue but apparently the nonlinearity of the problem prevents Mathematica from giving an asymptotic expansion. Hence I would like to ask if there are other built-in functions/packages that can solve these kinds of problems.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.